# how do I get name of the month in ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i create in my view:

```
<%=date=Date.today%>
```

How do i get the name of the month out of the date? I was trying to do sth like

```
 <%= DATE::ABBR_MONTHNAMES(date.month)%>
```

But without success. I keep getting an error: uninitialized constant `ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::MONTHNAMES`

How do i initialise the constant or is there any other way to get the name out of the Date format?

would greatly appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Ref [this](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime)

```
<% @date = Date.today  %>  
<%= @date.strftime("%B")%>
```

if

```
@date >> Fri, 11 Jun 2010
```

then

```
@date.strftime("%B") >> "June"
```

Comment: I wish there was `Date.today.month_name`.

Comment: @Chloe: 

class Date; def month_name; self.strftime("%B"); end; end

Comment: `Date.today.strftime("%B")`

Answer (score 32):

If you are looking solely to the month name, the `Date::MONTHNAMES` constant provided by rails is the easiest solution for you:

```
   Date::MONTHNAMES = 
   [
    [ 0] nil,
    [ 1] "January",
    [ 2] "February",
    [ 3] "March",
    [ 4] "April",
    [ 5] "May",
    [ 6] "June",
    [ 7] "July",
    [ 8] "August",
    [ 9] "September",
    [10] "October",
    [11] "November",
    [12] "December"
   ]
```

Comment: Date::MONTHNAMES[Time.zone.today.month]

Answer (score 18):

If you want a localized month name, try:

```
I18n.t('date.month_names')[date.month]
```

Example:

```
I18n.t('date.month_names')[12] #=> "Dezembro"
```

Comment: Rails i18n also provides `date.abbr_month_names` for shortened month names. There's a `nil` (blank) value at the beginning so `January` in English maps to index `1`. Source: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml#L19

Answer (score 5):

If you have a particular custom date / time format which you need to use repeatedly then you can extend the ActiveSupport date / time helper.

e.g. if you define the following in your config/environment.rb

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:full_english => "%A %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p")
```

then when you call `Time.now.to_s(:full_english)` in your views you will get something like:

```
"Friday June 11, 2010 at 12:53 PM"
```

Ruby's `strftime` method is well documented at http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime

Comment: Look at date/time converters to_formatted_s. This allows you to define date formats (like `:month_only`) and use date.to_formatted_s(:month_only) so you get maximum reuse for your strftime usage.

Answer (score 3):

Choose what you want

```
 Date.parse('5-jan-2017').strftime('%B')
```

Result:

> => "January"

```
Date.parse('5-jan-2017').strftime('%b')
```

Result:

> => "Jan"

For most of your further date related questions, refer this link
http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Answer (score 0):

this should help you 
https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/ruby-dates/cheatsheet

```
Date::MONTHNAMES
Date::DAYNAMES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use locales to display month names:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%F"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%b %d, %Y"
      month: "%b"
```

and to use it

```rb
i(Time.zone.today, format: :month)
```

[date/time formats](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)