# Transforming Datetime into month, day and year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to find this and I feel like it should be easy. In Ruby on Rails, how do I take:

```
2010-06-14 19:01:00 UTC
```

and turn it into

```
June 14th, 2010
```

Can I not just use a helper in the view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165170/in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-format-a-date-with-the-th-suffix-as-in-sun-oct-5t

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I don't know for

```
June 14th, 2010
```

But if you want

```
June 14, 2010
```

Ref   [how do i get name of the month in ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022163/how-do-i-get-name-of-the-month-in-ruby-on-rails/3022169#3022169)  or [this](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)

Just do

```
@date = Time.now
@date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

And for suffix use following

```
@date.strftime("%B #{@date.day.ordinalize}, %Y") # >>> Gives `June 18th, 2010`
```

Comment: Or if you want any other date, just convert it to date format first.

Comment: That's brilliant. And just revealed to me the strftime functions and each endless options.

Answer (score 7):

Time and date formats in rails:

Date

====

```
db:‘%Y-%m-%d’   2008-08-20

long_ordinal:‘&proc’      August 20th, 2008

long:‘%B %e, %Y’  August 20, 2008

rfc822:‘%e %b %Y’   20 Aug 2008

number:‘%Y%m%d’     20080820

short:‘%e %b’      20 Aug
```

DateTime

====

```
db:‘%Y-%m-%d’   2008-08-20 16:56:21

long_ordinal:‘&proc’      August 20th, 2008 16:56

long:‘%B %e, %Y’  August 20, 2008 16:56

rfc822:‘%e %b %Y’   Wed, 20 Aug 2008 16:56:21 -0600

number:‘%Y%m%d’     20080820165621

short:‘%e %b’      20 Aug 16:56
```

Time

====

```
db:‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S’         2008-08-20 16:56:21

long_ordinal:‘&proc’           August 20th, 2008 16:56

long:‘%B %d, %Y %H:%M’           August 20, 2008 16:56

rfc822:‘%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z’  Wed, 20 Aug 2008 16:56:21 -0600

short:‘%d %b %H:%M’               20 Aug 16:56

number:‘%Y%m%d%H%M%S’              20080820165621

time:‘%H:%M’                     16:56
```

for example:

```
<%= news.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M") %>
```

Thanks http://onrails.org/2008/08/20/what-are-all-the-rails-date-formats.html

Answer (score 6):

For future reference: [Rails date time formats](http://onrails.org/2008/08/20/what-are-all-the-rails-date-formats.html)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to save it in a variable.

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  # 2013-01-08
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs the Time module for `Time.parse` and ActiveSupport for `Integer#ordinalize`:

```
require 'time'
require 'active_support'

input = '2010-06-14 19:01:00 UTC'
t = Time.parse(input)
date = "%s %s, %d" % [t.strftime("%B"), t.day.ordinalize, t.year]
# => "June 14th, 2010"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the other day there was a similar question. In my answer [how do I get name of the month in ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022163/how-do-i-get-name-of-the-month-in-ruby-on-rails/3022466#3022466) I showed how you can add a custom `to_s` definition in your `config/environment.rb` file.

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
 :my_own_long_date_format => "%B %d, %Y")
```

Now you can call `Time.now.to_s(:my_own_long_date_format)` from any view to get:

```
June 15, 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Update that is working in Rails 5 :

```
<%= l @user.created_at, format: :short %>
```

Internationalize :

```
<%= I18n.l( @user.created_at, format: :short) %>
```

You can use :long instead of :short