# Date string to specific date format using Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
   test="2018-06-20 09:45:26.54"
```

want to convert this string to **June 20th 2018, 09:45:26.54** using Ruby.

Comment: What's your expected output, a _time_ instance or a different _string_ format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3045986/5101493

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Time.parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) :

```
require 'time'
Time.parse(test)
```

Or [Time.strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) if you know the exact format :

```
Time.strptime(test, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
```

or shorter :

```
Time.strptime(test, "%F %T.%L")
```

Once you have your `time` object :

```
time.strftime('%B %d %Y, %T.%L')
#=> "June 20 2018, 09:45:26.540"
```

If you want to get the exact same format as mentioned in your question :

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections"
# ^ No need for this line in Rails.

time.strftime("%B #{time.day.ordinalize} %Y, %T.%L").chomp('0')
# => "June 20th 2018, 09:45:26.54"
```